# React Native Regular Expression: How to remove a part from string and extract the url?

Tags: regex

I have a big string, which contains substrings in below format:

img[http://a.com/a.jpg]

If this substring is at the beginning ,it has no whitespace in front of img, otherwise there is always a whitespace before and after this substring.

I want:

1) extract all the urls inside [] and insert them into an array.

2) remove all the occurs in the big string.

Can anyone help to advise how to write the regular expression code?

Comment: What language are you using? Where is your code? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution ([live demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCr7QT/1)):

```
(\s?img\[(.*?)\]\s?)
```

The urls are in group 2, the substring to remove is in group 1.